# Why import of regular expressions falling a traceback error?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

Having assignment "Extracting Data With Regular Expressions". For this I'm importing regex, but the code is not working. what is my mistake?

I checked the code without "import", it does work.  Lines 2-7 are working. But it got a traceback error on "import re" line 1.

```
import re    
fname = input('Enter file: ') 
if len(fname) < 1 : fname = "sample.txt"
hand = open(fname)
hd = hand.read()    
for line in hand:
line = line.rstrip()
nm = re.findall('[0-9]+',line)
print(nm)



C:\Users\Desktop\new>re.py
Enter file:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Desktop\new\re.py", line 1, in <module>
 import re
File "C:\Users\Desktop\new\re.py", line 9, in <module>
 [enter image description here][1]nm = re.findall('[0-9]+',line)
AttributeError: module 're' has no attribute 'findall'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have called your file `re.py`, the `import` will actually import this file instead of the built-in module for regular expressions.

Just rename your file to something different and it should work as expected.

Comment: hey. Thanks. I changed the name of file, and previous files removed from folder. It is working)